# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in while installing drupal

Tags: 8, installation

I am new to drupal. I have downloaded and extracted drupal into a folder. I have installed apache and PHP on my Manjaro Linux.

here is my drupal specific apache conf:-

```
 Alias /noone/blogindrupal "/srv/http/noone/blogindrupal"
 <Directory "/srv/http/noone/blogindrupal">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks Indexes
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

When enter http://localhost/noone/blogindrupal in the browser URL bar, I get drupal installation page which following notice red box:-

```
 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (line 969 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Annotation/Doctrine/DocParser.php).
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (Line: 664)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Defines a form element plugin annotation object.
 *
 * See \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElementInterface for more information
 * about form element plugins.
 *
 * Plugin Namespace: Element
 *
 * For a working example, see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Textfield.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElementInterface
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\RenderElement
 * @see plugin_api
 *
 * @ingroup theme_render
 *
 * @Annotation
 */', 'class @Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\FormElement') (Line: 495)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->collectAnnotationMetadata('Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\FormElement') (Line: 720)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Provides an entity autocomplete form element.
 *
 * The #default_value accepted by this element is either an entity object or an
 * array of entity objects.
 *
 * @FormElement("entity_autocomplete")
 */', 'class Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete') (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotations(Object) (Line: 125)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotation(Object, 'Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\RenderElement') (Line: 145)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 110)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 77)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('form') (Line: 812)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->prepareForm('install_select_language_form', Array, Object) (Line: 278)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Object) (Line: 956)
install_get_form('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Array) (Line: 1376)
install_select_language(Array) (Line: 703)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 578)
install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (line 969 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Annotation/Doctrine/DocParser.php).
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (Line: 664)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Defines a render element plugin annotation object.
 *
 * See \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\ElementInterface for more information
 * about render element plugins.
 *
 * Plugin Namespace: Element
 *
 * For a working example, see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Link.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\ElementInterface
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\FormElement
 * @see plugin_api
 *
 * @ingroup theme_render
 *
 * @Annotation
 */', 'class @Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\RenderElement') (Line: 495)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->collectAnnotationMetadata('Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\RenderElement') (Line: 720)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Provides a link to break a tempstore lock.
 *
 * Properties:
 * - #label: The label of the object that is locked.
 * - #lock: \Drupal\Core\TempStore\Lock object.
 * - #url: \Drupal\Core\Url object pointing to the break lock form.
 *
 * Usage example:
 * @code
 * $build['examples_lock'] = [
 *   '#type' =&gt; 'break_lock_link',
 *   '#label' =&gt; $this-&gt;t('example item'),
 *   '#lock' =&gt; $tempstore-&gt;getMetadata('example_key'),
 *   '#url' =&gt; \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('examples.break_lock_form'),
 * ];
 * @endcode
 *
 * @RenderElement("break_lock_link")
 */', 'class Drupal\Core\TempStore\Element\BreakLockLink') (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotations(Object) (Line: 125)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotation(Object, 'Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\RenderElement') (Line: 145)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 110)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 77)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('form') (Line: 812)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->prepareForm('install_select_language_form', Array, Object) (Line: 278)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Object) (Line: 956)
install_get_form('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Array) (Line: 1376)
install_select_language(Array) (Line: 703)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 578)
install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (line 969 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Annotation/Doctrine/DocParser.php).
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (Line: 664)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Defines a config entity type annotation object.
 *
 * The annotation properties of entity types are found on
 * \Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityType and are accessed using
 * get/set methods defined in \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface.
 *
 * @ingroup entity_api
 *
 * @Annotation
 */', 'class @Drupal\Core\Entity\Annotation\ConfigEntityType') (Line: 495)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->collectAnnotationMetadata('Drupal\Core\Entity\Annotation\ConfigEntityType') (Line: 720)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Defines the entity form mode configuration entity class.
 *
 * Form modes allow entity forms to be displayed differently depending on the
 * context. For instance, the user entity form can be displayed with a set of
 * fields on the 'profile' page (user edit page) and with a different set of
 * fields (or settings) on the user registration page. Modules taking part in
 * the display of the entity form (notably the Field API) can adjust their
 * behavior depending on the requested form mode. An additional 'default' form
 * mode is available for all entity types. For each available form mode,
 * administrators can configure whether it should use its own set of field
 * display settings, or just replicate the settings of the 'default' form mode,
 * thus reducing the amount of form display configurations to keep track of.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface::getAllFormModes()
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface::getFormModes()
 *
 * @ConfigEntityType(
 *   id = "entity_form_mode",
 *   label = @Translation("Form mode"),
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "label"
 *   },
 *   config_export = {
 *     "id",
 *     "label",
 *     "targetEntityType",
 *     "cache",
 *   }
 * )
 */', 'class Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormMode') (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotations(Object) (Line: 125)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotation(Object, 'Drupal\Core\Entity\Annotation\EntityType') (Line: 145)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('date_format', ) (Line: 143)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition('date_format') (Line: 269)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler('date_format', 'storage') (Line: 208)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getStorage('date_format') (Line: 93)
Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatter->__construct(Object, Object, Object, Object, Object)
ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array) (Line: 1176)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object, Array, 1, 'date.formatter') (Line: 634)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet('date.formatter', 1) (Line: 588)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('date.formatter') (Line: 87)
Drupal\Core\TempStore\Element\BreakLockLink::create(Object, Array, 'break_lock_link', Array) (Line: 21)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('break_lock_link', Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('break_lock_link', Array) (Line: 141)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->createInstance('break_lock_link') (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 77)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('form') (Line: 812)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->prepareForm('install_select_language_form', Array, Object) (Line: 278)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Object) (Line: 956)
install_get_form('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Array) (Line: 1376)
install_select_language(Array) (Line: 703)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 578)
install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (line 969 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Annotation/Doctrine/DocParser.php).
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Identifier() (Line: 664)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Defines a translatable annotation object.
 *
 * Some metadata within an annotation needs to be translatable. This class
 * supports that need by allowing both the translatable string and, if
 * specified, a context for that string. The string (with optional context)
 * is passed into t().
 *
 * @ingroup plugin_translatable
 *
 * @Annotation
 */', 'class @Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation') (Line: 495)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->collectAnnotationMetadata('Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation') (Line: 720)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 1009)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->PlainValue() (Line: 1061)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->FieldAssignment() (Line: 991)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Value() (Line: 860)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Values() (Line: 835)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->MethodCall() (Line: 746)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotation() (Line: 640)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->Annotations() (Line: 338)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\DocParser->parse('/**
 * Defines the entity form mode configuration entity class.
 *
 * Form modes allow entity forms to be displayed differently depending on the
 * context. For instance, the user entity form can be displayed with a set of
 * fields on the 'profile' page (user edit page) and with a different set of
 * fields (or settings) on the user registration page. Modules taking part in
 * the display of the entity form (notably the Field API) can adjust their
 * behavior depending on the requested form mode. An additional 'default' form
 * mode is available for all entity types. For each available form mode,
 * administrators can configure whether it should use its own set of field
 * display settings, or just replicate the settings of the 'default' form mode,
 * thus reducing the amount of form display configurations to keep track of.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface::getAllFormModes()
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface::getFormModes()
 *
 * @ConfigEntityType(
 *   id = "entity_form_mode",
 *   label = @Translation("Form mode"),
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "label"
 *   },
 *   config_export = {
 *     "id",
 *     "label",
 *     "targetEntityType",
 *     "cache",
 *   }
 * )
 */', 'class Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormMode') (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotations(Object) (Line: 125)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\SimpleAnnotationReader->getClassAnnotation(Object, 'Drupal\Core\Entity\Annotation\EntityType') (Line: 145)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('date_format', ) (Line: 143)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition('date_format') (Line: 269)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler('date_format', 'storage') (Line: 208)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getStorage('date_format') (Line: 93)
Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatter->__construct(Object, Object, Object, Object, Object)
ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array) (Line: 1176)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object, Array, 1, 'date.formatter') (Line: 634)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet('date.formatter', 1) (Line: 588)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('date.formatter') (Line: 87)
Drupal\Core\TempStore\Element\BreakLockLink::create(Object, Array, 'break_lock_link', Array) (Line: 21)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('break_lock_link', Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('break_lock_link', Array) (Line: 141)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->createInstance('break_lock_link') (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 77)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('form') (Line: 812)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->prepareForm('install_select_language_form', Array, Object) (Line: 278)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Object) (Line: 956)
install_get_form('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Array) (Line: 1376)
install_select_language(Array) (Line: 703)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 578)
install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
```

Also if continue and enter database information and press submit button, after few seconds I get Gateway Timeout error like:-

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect you are installing Drupal (or at least trying to) on a server running PHP 7.4, which is not currently compatible with the latest version of Drupal (8.8). There is an issue on drupal.org right here that details the current problems, including yours: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3086374 .

The highest supported version of Drupal 8.8 is currently 7.3: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements .

Comment: Yes. I am using 7.4

Comment: I've experienced the same issue and have to downgrade the PHP version using the following link  https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-downgrade-php-74-to-73-ubuntuexample.html

Comment: Yes its PHP version Compatibility issue, downgrading back to 7.3 fixes this issue