# Class "\Drupal\system\Controller\Http4xxController" does not exist

Tags: 8, installation, composer

I'm using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project to install Drupal 8. The only thing I've changed in the `composer.json` is to freeze Drupal core version to 8.8.1

After Drupal installation I get WSOD and see the following errors in PHP logs:

> Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Class "\Drupal\system\Controller\Http4xxController" does not exist." at /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php line 24
> Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "No check has been registered for access_check.permission" at /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Access/CheckProvider.php line 97

It happens with PHP 7.2 and 7.3, but not with Drupal 8.8.0. It happens regardless of whether you freeze Drupal core or not, and with the (now) official Composer template (drupal/recommended-project) too.

This issue happens only when installing from web.

Comment: Have you already tried `composer update --lock && composer install`? Or if this didn't work `rm -rf vendor/ && rm -rf composer.lock && composer install`? And what do you mean by `Drupal installation`? How did you install? On an existing installation or a fresh install?

Comment: The [`Http4xxController`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Controller%21Http4xxController.php/class/Http4xxController/8.8.x) class exists in Drupal 8.8.x. It seems that the dependencies have not been all installed.

Comment: @leymannx this is a fresh install https://github.com/wodby/drupal/blob/master/8/Dockerfile#L19-L25. By installation, I mean clean drupal installation from a browser. You can clone latest https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal and try it yourself

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've looked it up and the class with this namespace actually exists in the codebase. So it's not a composer dependencies issue. Most likely something wrong with the dependency injection container built after the installation

Comment: Something's going on in the install itself. It was spewing a bunch of errors on the install.php and during the installer batch.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/289214/notice-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null-in-while-installing

Comment: I cloned docker4drupal and didn't change any defaults and I got PHP 7.4. It looks like something in one of the Dockerfiles is upgrading to 7.4. `wodby@php.container:/var/www/html/web $ php --version
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 19 2019 04:13:09) ( NTS )`

Comment: @mradcliffe if you update .env tags in docker4drupal to PHP 7.2 or 7.3 you'll see the error (`DRUPAL_TAG=8-7.3`)

Comment: This is a valid bug, I created an issue for it at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3103529 - it seems to happen only on http installation for me.

Comment: If it's a bug it belongs on drupal.org and is off-topic for Drupal Answers. Bugs must not be handled here but in the corresponding issue queues.